# Is cloudSim flexible enough for my project?

Tags: simulation, cloud, job-scheduler

I'm working in a new scheduler for a cloud infrastructure. I need to simulate an architecture where jobs are stored in a database and workers nodes do queries in that database to recuperate the jobs and treat them. Does anyone know any framework that will suit my needs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about recommending software that meets specific requirements – not the other way around. For details, see [Are “Can I use X for Y” questions on-topic?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2816/185) If you can **[edit]** your question in a way reflecting that, please do so and we can reopen it for answers.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are reinventing the wheel. Rather than ask for a framework, then spend months coding & testing, why not list your requirements & ask us for some (FOSS) library?